# For, While, Do Loops causing strange error in iteration, concerning variables

Tags: c#, winforms, for-loop, while-loop, gdi+

So I'm a noob, please put that in context. I'm sorry if I've missed anything obvious.

Observe the following method:

```
public static void DrawImageRepeatHoriz(Bitmap i, int y)
{
    int counter = 0;                
    while (counter < 4)
    {
        paint_order.Enqueue(() => buffer.Graphics.DrawImage(i, new 
        Point(50 * counter, 0)));
        counter++;                    
    }

    /*paint_order.Enqueue(() => buffer.Graphics.DrawImage(i, new 
    Point(0 * 50, 0)));
    paint_order.Enqueue(() => buffer.Graphics.DrawImage(i, new 
    Point(1 * 50, 0)));
    paint_order.Enqueue(() => buffer.Graphics.DrawImage(i, new 
    Point(2 * 50, 0)));
    paint_order.Enqueue(() => buffer.Graphics.DrawImage(i, new 
    Point(3 * 50, 0)));*/
}
```

The method should accept an Image and a Y value. What it does with those is that at that y value the image will be drawn a few times - enough for it to at least fill the screen.

So it repeats the image across the screen along the point on the y-axis.

As you can see I've removed a majority of that logic, because I have to debug something that's getting in my way.

- When I use the for loop equivalent of the while loop present, or the while loop itself, it seems that `int counter` becomes unavailable until the loop ends. what I mean by this is that the logic there that multiplies 50 by counter only happens once despite the fact that it is run several times. What this causes is that instead of there being four images that have resulted from repeating, there is only one image - the last image out of the four.
- Naturally, the code I have blocked off as a comment in which the repeating is done manually works. I mean, of course, it should work and so should the for and while loops. But somehow, for some reason when the counter variable is being used for iteration, the logic just falters.

**The other stuff here is that** `buffer` **has been created properly by allocating using the current context and g which was returned by** `SomeForm.CreateGraphics()` **So please don't worry about the graphics it works fine when I do it manually as I said.** `buffer` **is valid, and the parameters being used are valid.**

Thanks in advance.

This is very frustrating.

EDIT: Silly me, I did not explain `paint_order`.

```
static Queue<Action> paint_order = new Queue<Action>(20);
```

Comment: The code enqueues the same object over and over again.  So all queue entries are identical to the last one.  Use the new Bitmap(Image) constructor to create a true copy.

Comment: That occurred to me and I tried that, perhaps I did something incorrectly when I tried.

I will try again.

Comment: @HansPassant Okay so I've tried and failed again. But now that I think about it, if it worked manually that means that `Action`s being enqueued are not the same.

That can also be seen from the fact that, despite the same image being used a `new Point` object is always created. So they can't be the same right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems that there's always the same reference to `counter` variable passed to lambdas you queue and those functions are invoked after the loop runs (this way everytime it refers to `counter` it will be 3) - I've introduced new variable instantiated every time new value needs to be calculated:

```
for (int counter = 0; counter < 4; counter ++)
{
    var pointCoord = 50 * counter;
    paint_order.Enqueue(() => buffer.Graphics.DrawImage(i, new 
    Point(pointCoord, 0)));
}
```

Comment: Okay, I will try this immediately! Thank you! I will be sure to like this if it works.

Comment: Yes, it works. 

It's so weird that I can't use it directly though, I must get used to this.

Comment: This baited me in the butt a few months back

Comment: @Dominic when you used `counter` directly in the question, all the queued functions refered to the same `counter` variable (the same place in memory) so when they were executed (after your method ends) the place in memory where `counter` was stored was already set to 3 (after the loop ends).
The code in my response creates new variable (in the new place in memory) with every iteration so each of the functions refer to different values

Comment: `It's so weird that I can't use it directly though` @Dominic the key to understanding this is to realise that while there is a separate `pointCoord` variable for each loop iteration (i.e. 4 of them) there is only **one** `counter`.

Comment: Ah, I get it now. I didn't know it worked like that.
@mjwills Thanks as well.